# Openbox overwrites xmodmap configuration

Tags: linux-mint, openbox, xmodmap, xkb

I am setting up openbox on my laptop running Linux Mint 13. I want my Caps Lock key to act as an additional control key. I put the required settings in my `~/.Xmodmap` file and checked it by running

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

It works correctly.

However when I relogin to my openbox session, these key changes are not present. Running the above `xmodmap` command gets it working again, but I want it to happen automatically at startup.

What's interesting is that I added a test `zenity` command as following to my `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file

```
zenity --info --text=Hello
```

This produces a small dialog window and exits only after the dialog is closed.

Now, when I relogin to my openbox session, the Caps Lock acts as a Ctrl key, *until* the zenity dialog is closed. Once that dialog is closed, the Caps Lock returns to its default behavior.

I haven't found anything on this with google so I'm asking for help here. Do you guys have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

### Update:

I have been trying to figure this out and in my experiments, I copied my `/usr/bin/xmodmap` file to `/usr/bin/xmodmap_` and replaced the `/usr/bin/xmodmap` file with the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    echo '-------'
    date
    echo xmodmap "$@"
} >> ~/xmodmap-calls

exec /usr/bin/xmodmap_ "$@"
```

So, every time any damn script on the system runs `xmodmap`, I get to know it.

With this, I relogin and I only find one entry in my `~/xmodmap-calls` file, which is the one running my `~/.Xmodmap`, which is expected. So, I figured its not a `xmodmap` that is overwriting my changes.

Next, a bit of googling introduced me to the `setxkbmap` command, which apparently can also do the same thing. I replaced that executable also, similar to xmodmap above. And I got the culprit command!

```
setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

I have absolutely no idea what that does, but after running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` (which applied my settings correctly), if I run the above command, my changes are reset! *Edit*: This is turning out real funny. Just a `setxkbmap` command without any arguments, happily overwrites my changes by the `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` command.

Now I have two things to figure out, where is this `setxkbmap` being run from & why and how to fix this. I'm still investigation but could seriously use some help :)

### Update 2

To hell with `xmodmap`. I can't figure out where the `setxkbmap` is being called from, but I figured a way to use `setxkbmap` command to make my Caps Lock behave as Ctrl.

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

Just before starting openbox. Works brilliant. The caps lock key stays acting as a ctrl key. `xmodmap` is never run.

I'll keep this question here open so someone who knows these things can provide some insight. Also, for people who face this after me :)

### Update 3

Here's the contents of my `.config/openbox/autostart`, as requested by pedrosaurio.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the wallpaper.
feh --bg-scale /wall.png

# Set default brightness.
xbacklight -time 1 '=40'

# Compositing.
xcompmgr &

# The panel.
tint2 &

# Start a terminal too.
roxterm &
```

This doesn't have anything to do with the keyboard, as far as I can tell. Also, here's the script that starts my session: (Run by lightdm)

```
#!/bin/bash

setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps

exec openbox-session
```

Comment: you are probably using some kind of keyboard configuration, e.g. choose the keyboard layout or something similar which reverts your applied changes

Comment: The only other place I fiddled with keyboard configuration is the GUI keyboard layout preferences window, where I changed the caps lock key to behave as an additional ctrl. That works fine, in the cinnamon DE, my caps lock acts as a ctrl even after a relogin. I think that configuration was cinnamon-only, but I'm not sure.

Comment: how are you adding the command in the autostart script?

Comment: Can you post your `autostart` file?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar problem. It turned out that it was caused by ibus. I simply uninstalled it as I don't need its services.

I found the culprit by using your trick of replacing setxkbmap by a script, however I also added `ps -AF --forest` to identify the caller of setxkbmap.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your autostart script my bet is that you are not using the proper syntax by letting your commands run in the background using the ampersand (`&`).

Try editing your `.config/openbox/autostart` file so it looks like this:

```
# Run the system-wide support stuff
#. $GLOBALAUTOSTART
# Programs to launch at startup
# Programs that will run after Openbox has started
(sleep 1 && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap ) &
```

If in doubt have a look in the openbox wiki and see how all the examples have `&` after each entry.

http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart

Comment: My autostart file is empty. At a point I did have `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in that file (without an `&`, didn't seem necessary). I have been calling `xmodmap` (and now `setxkbmap`) in the script that start my openbox session. Just before running `exec openbox-session`, I run the `setxkbmap` command.

Comment: Also, adding a `sleep 1` delay so that `xmodmap` applies its changes after everything else loads is, while works most of the time, doesn't make me feel too confident about the solution. I'd prefer not to do it, if I have alternatives.

Comment: You can avoid obviously all the comments and the `sleep` command, nevertheless the `&` is necessary after each entry, otherwise all the programs after the first entry will not run at all.

Comment: Yes, if its a long running app/process, not adding a `&` will make it block. I used this behavior with the `zenity` command to find that my `xmodmap` changes are being overwritten *after* `autostart` finishes. My autostart is now growing in size and will paste it in the question in a moment. It doesn't have anything to do with the keyboard, though.

Comment: And, without the sleep command, the changes made by `xmodmap` are overwritten as soon as the autostart file finishes.