# `xmodmap` not working on startup

Tags: login, xmodmap

I recently installed Debian 9 and inserted my usual `~/.Xmodmap` file and added `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to my `.xsession`. To my disappointment this didn't actually work.

For reference, I run `i3` from `startx` without a DM.

To test if the command ran successfully I replaced the command in my `.xsession` with `touch ~/prior && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap && touch ~/post`. And the files were in fact created indicating that the `xmodmap` command was indeed ran correctly but the mappings were reset somewhere, probably by a call to `setxkbmap`.

I searched for a solution and found only questions without answers, or questions with old answers that didn't work for me, or that contained no real solution:

- [Why won't my ~/.Xmodmap file load on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7190/why-wont-my-xmodmap-file-load-on-login)
- [Why won't my xmodmap command run on startup/login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login)
- [How do I set Xmodmap on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login)
- [Openbox overwrites xmodmap configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/openbox-overwrites-xmodmap-configuration?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this behavior to be indirectly documented in `man keyboard`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  keyboard  file describes the properties of the keyboard. It is read by **setupcon(1)** in order to configure the keyboard on the console.  In Debian systems the default keyboard layout is described in /etc/default/keyboard **and it is shared between  X and the console.**

The contents of `/etc/default/keyboard` are generated on system install and gave a hint to the actual problem (I added the `ctrl:nocaps` option later):

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="se"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

The above together indicates that X will set the xkb options at some point during startup (probably after `.xsession` and the like) which causes any `xmodmap` settings set during `.xsession` to be lost.

So there is the cause, the solution is hinted at from `man setupcon`:

> The keyboard configuration is specified in ~/.keyboard or /etc/default/keyboard.  The **font  configuration**  is  specified  in  ~/.console-setup  or **/etc/default/console-setup**.

Checking `man console-setup` yields:

> The  file  console-setup specifies the encoding and the font to be used by setupcon(1) in order to setup the console.  **It can be used also to specify the keyboard layout** but it is not recommended to do so, use keyboard(5) instead.

So `/etc/default/keyboard` is used to set keyboard settings for TTY and X. While `/etc/default/console-setup` is can be used to setup keyboard (not really recommended but works) and font for console only.

So to make this all work I moved `/etc/default/keyboard`  to `/etc/default/console-setup` and added the following to my `.xsession`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The below assumes bash features, rewrite if you use other shells.
source /etc/default/console-setup

XKBPARMS=""
if [[ "$XKBLAYOUT" ]]; then
   XKBPARMS="-layout $XKBLAYOUT"
fi

if [[ "$XKBMODEL" ]]; then
    XKBPARMS+=" -model $XKBMODEL"
fi

if [[ "$XKBVARIANT" ]]; then
    XKBPARMS+=" -variant $XKBVARIANT"
fi

if [[ "$XKBOPTIONS" ]]; then
    XKBPARMS+=" -option $XKBOPTIONS"
fi

if [[ "$XKBPARMS" ]]; then
    setxkbmap $XKBPARMS
fi

xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Now `xmodmap` works correctly and I have the correct keymap and options in both the TTY and in X.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having issues with `xmodmap`-type solutions, so after some research I decided to use `xkb` directly. I also found that [the archwiki does not recommend `xmodmap` for anything but "the simplest" tasks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension#xmodmap):

> Generally it is not recommended to use xmodmap, except maybe for the simplest tasks. XKB-compatible equivalent of xmodmap is xkbcomp; however, xkbcomp lacks -e option, so it is not that simple. Anyway, whenever possible, xkbcomp should be preferred.

The following solution worked for me (on Ubuntu 16.04):

- In TTYs: [how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux/290149#290149).
- In `X`: backup and modify the relevant files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. I have changes in `us` (for number row and a few other things) and `pc` (for capslock).

Unfortunately, this does mean keeping track of two separate solutions for `X` and the TTY, but it's been alright with me so far.

But if you have an `xmodmap` solution that works already, that's all that matters!

Comment: Yes, I looked at `xkb` but it seemed way too complicated for the equivalent `xmodmap`. Specifically I remap right `Ctrl` to become `Mod3` instead of functioning as a control modifier. This becomes my mod key for i3 which is easier to use on my hands than the `Win` which breaks my fingers and `Alt` conflicts with just about every other keybinding I use. But thanks for the comment, I'm sure it will be useful to someone who doesn't have a weird key rebinding schema. :)